# Section headers in lightning-record-form

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-record-form

I am displaying a `Full` layout on `Desktop` using `lightning-record-form` for my custom object.

The order of fields matches my layout, however all section headers are hidden. Is there a way to show them?

In my layout `Display section header` is checked for both `Edit Page` and `Detail Page`.

There is only one record type for this object (`Master`).

Note: the end goal of what i want to achieve is a standard layout locked to read only that each admin in their subscriber org can edit as they please, but can never make editable. I am an ISV so i publish a Managed Package on App Exchange.

The object in question is a custom object shipped in the same Managed Package.

Answer (score 0):

There is no provision to create sections and section headers in the `lightning-record-form`. You need to use `lightning-record-edit-form` instead of that, it fully is customizable and you can mimic the standard layout in there. You can create sections using it.

[Record Edit Form](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-record-edit-form/documentation)

Comment: Except i can't use `lightning-record-edit-form` to automatically fetch those sections and fields for me. Ah well. Thanks.

Comment: yeah you need to mention the fields, as well as you, need to write the HTML markup to create the layout `using lightning-input-field` and section headers.

Comment: Yeah so this is why this answer is not helpful for me :(

Comment: @zaitsman are you using this on the custom object?

Comment: Yes, i am using this on the custom object

Comment: If you just want to set visibility of the fields based on conditions, you can use Dynamic Forms feature which just released in Summer 20, I have written a [blog post](https://sftrailmixer.blogspot.com/2020/05/how-to-create-dynamic-form-action-saleforce.html) on how to use that.

Comment: it's non GA preview, i can't use this in a Managed package.

Comment: Also, it just allows me to drag and drop sections, not 'make the layout readonly for everyone'.]

Comment: If you want it configurable, you can use custom metadata to store the fields and section details, and render the layout based on that.